# Personalizar Auth de Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una gran duda, hoy estuve curioseando el Auth de Laravel, el problema que no pude resolver fue lo siguiente:

Modifiqué la migración users por:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sis_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_user');
            $table->string('name_user');
            $table->string('email_user')->unique();
            $table->string('password_user');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Modifiqué los Modelos, pero aun no logro encontrar los demás archivos donde debo realizar más modificaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tenés que hacer es modificar la migración, el Modelo, el controlador y la Vista del formulario de Login.

Justo ayer hice un gist en github para explicar esto. [Como hacer login con username en lugar de por email en Laravel](https://gist.github.com/amamarul/e73a6651d97eb2bc256666275d3b0db3). Igualmente te pongo la explicación y el código acá. Espero sea lo que necesitás.
Saludos

El controlador `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` implementa el trait `AuthenticatesUsers` y este es el encargado de realizar la validación del Login. El método `validateLogin()` valida el campo `email` por defecto pero este lo obtiene del método `username()` que retorna el campo `email` por eso si lo que queremos es validar el login por otro campo (En este ejemplo será el campo **'username'**) debemos:

1- En la migracion de la tabla `users` (`2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`) agregar el campo `username` es importante que este sea de tipo `unique`

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

2- En el modelo `App\User` agregar el campo `username` a los fillables.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

3- En el controlador `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` agregar el método `username()`

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

4- En la vista blade `auth/login.blade.php` modificar el formulario de login. En lugar de un campo de tipo `email` colocamos como campo `text` y además tenemos que cambiar el name.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('username'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Y listo, podemos utilizar el auth por defecto de Laravel pero ahora nos logueamos utilizando el **username** en lugar del **email**

Comment: Si, estas en lo correcto. Pero en este caso tambien quiero que el password sea password_user, También cambié el nombre de la tabla pero eso ya lo declaré en el Modelo protected $table = 'sis_users'.

Comment: hola @Maru Amallo, estos pasos me sirven exactamente si yo tengo la base de datos creada por separado? es decir no corrí ninguna migración? hice el SQL desde consola para crear todas mis tablas

Comment: Hola Alfredo, claro que sirven. Siempre y cuando las tablas respeten la estructura no debería haber problema. Las migraciones son solo una especie de control de versiones de la estructura de la base de datos y te recomiendo ampliamente que las uses, sobre todo cuando estas en etapa de desarrollo ya que es muy facil hacer un refresh completo de la base en milesimas de segundos y si usas los seeders tambien en cuestion de segundos podes reproducir una base de datos completa. Es excelente para jugar! jaja