# ¿Como hacer un login en Laravel usando un modelo y campos diferentes a los que trae por default?

Tags: laravel, login

espero me puedan ayudar por favor.
Recientemente empecé a usar Laravel y estoy practicando haciendo un sistema de logueo, quiero usar las funciones que Laravel trae para autenticar usuarios pero usando un modelo diferente al que trae por default (user) y autenticando al usuario con un campo diferente al email.

Ya logré hacer la conexión de la BD y ya probé haciendo unas consultas en el controlador y todo va bien. Ahora quiero loguear al usuario con esta función

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }else{
        return back();
    }
```

pero la función siempre cae en el `else`.

Ya estuve buscando casos similares, hay varios, pero he probado con las soluciones propuestas, y no logro tener éxito.

Muchas gracias, de antemano. En verdad ya leí y probé bastante antes de llegar acá.

**RUTAS**

```
Route::get('/', 'FormulariosController@index');
Route::post('/login', 'FormulariosController@iniciarSesion');
Route::get('/www', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
public function index(){
    return view('formularios');
}
protected $redirectTo = '/www';
public function iniciarSesion(Request $request){    
    $matricula = Input::get('matriculaI');   
    $password = Input::get('password');         
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }else{
        return back();
    }
}
```

**VISTA**

```
        <aside id="columna">
            <header>
                INICIO DE SESI&Oacute;N
            </header><br>
            <form action= {{ url('/login') }} method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="form" value="formIngresar">

                Matr&iacute;cula 
                <input class="entradaLogueo" type="text" name="matriculaI"> <br><br>
                Contrase&ntilde;a <br>
                <input class="entradaLogueo" type="password" name="password"><br><br>

                <input type="submit" name="ingresar" value="Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n" onclick="return validarSesion(this.form)">
            </form>         

        </aside>
```

**MODELO**

```
<?php  
namespace App;  
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Usuario extends Model{
protected $table = 'usuarios';
protected $primaryKey = 'matricula';
public $incrementing = 'false';
protected $keyType = 'string';
protected $fillable = ['nombres', 'correo', 'password',];
protected $hidden = ['password',];
public function username(){  
    return 'matricula';
}
public function getAuthPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}  
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
    'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Usuario::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Comment: Te comparto una respuesta que hice ya hace un tiempo, espero que te ayude.  
[Personalizar Auth de Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162111/57312)

Comment: @MaruAmallo ¿Por qué no pones el comentario como respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Segun entiendo lo que querés hacer es modificar el nombre del Modelo `User` y en lugar de ingresar usando un email lo que querés es usar un numero de matrícula.
Como siempre en programación hay muchas maneras de hacer eso.

La que considero la mejor opción está en el siguiente enlace [Personalizar Auth de Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/162111/57312).
Si seguís los pasos lo vas a lograr en muy poco tiempo.  En tu caso solo sería colocar `matricula` en lugar de `username`.

Si aun consideras importante cambiar el nombre al modelo simplemente lo renombras y actualizar en `config/auth.php` el modelo como ya hiciste.

Espero mi respuesta sea de ayuda y cualquier cosa por acá ando.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Hice el make:auth para probar lo que me dices, pero por alguna razón no puedo hacer el logueo, me dice que las credenciales no están registradas, y ya verifiqué la conexión a la BD y sí funciona.¿Se necesita cambiar establecer el campo que se usará como autenticador en algún otro archivo?

Comment: Po que no probas siguiendo los pasos para una instalacion nueva fuera de tu proyecto actual. Hacé un `laravel new nombre-app` modificá el archivo `.env` con una base de datos vacía, despues corré el comando `php artisan make:auth`, despues `php artisan migrate`, despues `php artisan tinker`, despues escribí `factory(App\User::class)->create(['email' => 'admin@admin.com']);` y Control+C para salir de tinker. Eso ya te habilitaría a hacer un login con el mail `admin@admin.com` y la password `secret` y bueno despues seguir los pasos para personalizar el auth